# Oracle SQL: Between From_date and To_date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am want to select between a date from - date to - I am getting error invalid number

```
  SELECT tt.id_str_rt store
        ,SUBSTR(tt.inf_ct,1,5) zip_code
        ,COUNT(tt.ai_trn) tran_count
        ,SUM(tr.mo_nt_tot) sales_value
    FROM orco_owner.tr_trn tt
        ,orco_owner.tr_rtl tr
   WHERE tt.id_str_rt = tr.id_str_rt
     AND tt.id_str_rt = NVL(:PM_store_number,tt.id_str_rt)
     AND NVL(SUBSTR(tt.inf_ct,1,5),0) = NVL(:PM_zip_code,NVL(SUBSTR(tt.inf_ct,1,5),0))
     AND tt.id_ws = tr.id_ws
     AND tt.dc_dy_bsn = tr.dc_dy_bsn
     AND tt.ai_trn = tr.ai_trn
     AND TRUNC(TO_DATE(tt.dc_dy_bsn,'yyyy-MM-dd')) 
 BETWEEN TO_DATE(TRUNC(NVL(:PM_date_from,TO_DATE('1901-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd'))),'yyyy-MM-dd') 
     AND TO_DATE (NVL(:PM_date_to, '2099-12-31'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
     AND LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(inf_ct,1,5), '0123456789', ' '))) IS NULL
GROUP BY tt.id_str_rt,SUBSTR(tt.inf_ct,1,5)
ORDER BY zip_code   ;
```

Comment: Can you interchangeably use 'yyyy-MM-dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: Show us the complete stored procedure

Comment: The problem may be here: `TRUNC(NVL(:PM_date_from,TO_DATE('1901-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd'))` - if `:PM_date_from` is passed as a string, then the second argument (if ever used) will be converted to string also, using your `nls_date_format`, and in all cases `TRUNC(...)` will be evaluated on a string, which makes no sense: "invalid number" since it's not a number. You get the same error if you `select trunc('x') from dual`.

Comment: If you need help fixing this, please post your PROBLEM STATEMENT (input tables and columns, a description of the requirement in common English, **not through code**, and desired results, with small data sample and expected output).

Answer (score 0):

Why do everything twice? Try this:

```
TO_DATE(NVL(TRIM(:PM_date_from),'1901-01-01'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Trim the value if it is null replace with default then convert to date.

The error you are getting could be `:PM_date_from` is malformed or it could be `'yyyy-mm-dd'` should be `'yyyy-MM-dd'`

Comment: What data type did you assume for `:PM_date_from` here? I am unable to make sense of this, any more than what the OP had. If it is a string, as suggested by the alternative value in `NVL`, what does it mean to truncate a character string? If it is supposed to be a date, that will be a data type mismatch in `NVL`.

Comment: @mathguy -- good point it only makes sense to trim a string -- which is what I meant.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP meant though; I think he is taking a date, he is truncating it, and then he does some odd things with it. Anyway - we are all still waiting for the OP to explain **what** he was attempting to do (which should never be done through code, especially code that *doesn't* do what its author intended).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the following code working in SQL Developer, but in BI Publisher 10 G I get "Not a valid month"

```
 SELECT tt.id_str_rt store
       ,SUBSTR(tt.inf_ct,1,5) zip_code
       ,COUNT(tt.ai_trn) tran_count
       ,SUM(tr.mo_nt_tot) sales_value  
    FROM orco_owner.tr_trn tt
       ,orco_owner.tr_rtl tr
    WHERE tt.id_str_rt = tr.id_str_rt
    AND tt.id_str_rt = NVL(:PM_store_number,tt.id_str_rt)
    AND NVL(SUBSTR(tt.inf_ct,1,5),0) = NVL(:PM_zip_code,NVL(SUBSTR(tt.inf_ct,1,5),0))
    AND tt.id_ws = tr.id_ws
    AND tt.dc_dy_bsn = tr.dc_dy_bsn
    AND tt.ai_trn = tr.ai_trn
    AND TRUNC (TO_DATE(tt.dc_dy_bsn,'yyyy-MM-dd'))
    BETWEEN TO_DATE (NVL(:PM_date_from, '1901/01/01'),'yyyy/MM/dd')
    AND TO_DATE (NVL(:PM_date_to, '2099/01/01'),'yyyy/MM/dd')   
    AND LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(inf_ct,1,5), '0123456789', ' '))) IS NULL
    GROUP BY tt.id_str_rt,SUBSTR(tt.inf_ct,1,5)
    ORDER BY zip_code, store ;
```